# Angular file upload with Body data

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I use [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)  in my project. Everything is working fine and I use it like below.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="file" ngf-select=""
    ngf-change="validateFileInput($files)" ngf-multiple="false"
    ngf-allow-dir="false" ng-model="contactGroupForm.files"
    id="fileUpload" name="file" required="File must be selected">
</div>
```

Angular controller,

```
var paramsData = {'name' : $scope.form.groupName,'description': $scope.form.groupDesc };
Upload.upload({
            url: restUrl,
            method: "POST",
            timeout: 200000,
            params : paramsData,
            file : $scope.file
        }).then(success, error);
```

The Spring rest controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public StatusDto saveContactGroup(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            @RequestParam("contactGroupId") String contactGroupId,
            @RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam(value="description", required=false) String description) {
```

Now, we are planning to have more input in the forms. So, I would like to send everything through @RequestBody to the spring rest controller.

But, it does not work as expected and i get bad request error.

```
$scope.formData = {                
                'name': $scope.contactGroupForm.groupName,
                'desc': $scope.contactGroupForm.groupDesc,
                'file': $scope.file
            };

 Upload.upload({
                url: restUrl,
                method: "POST",
                timeout: 200000,
                file : data
            }).then(success, error);
```

Spring controller,

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/contact/saveContactGroup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public StatusDto saveContactGroup(@RequestBody ContactForm) {
```

Is there anyway, we can wrap the file and the form data in a form to send to the Spring rest controller?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need `@RequestBody`, but you still need `@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file`.

Comment: How can i send other form parameters?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You do it like in example 1 but with the Spring code from example 2 and the modifications from my comment.

Comment: I follow example 1. But would like to go with example 2 as there are many other form fields which i dont want to send as request params.

Comment: `paramsData` is sent in the body.

Comment: paramsData is seen in the request URL not in the body.

Comment: I see. Then try `data: $scope.formData` instead of `file: data`.

Comment: I tried this and getting bad data error.

Comment: Did you apply the modifications from my first comments? They are necessary nonetheless.

Comment: With first comment, I can send file data, but How can i sent other form parameters with @RequestBody?

Comment: If you use `ContactForm` without `@RequestBody` it should be populated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

From my project

```
 Upload.upload({
            url: 'rest/upload',
            data: {file: files, 'objectId':$stateParams.objectId}
        }).then(function (resp) {
           //console.log(resp);
            $scope.loadDocList();
        }, function (resp) {
           // console.log(resp);
        }, function (evt) {
            $scope.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
            //console.log($scope.progress);
            if($scope.progress==100)$scope.progress = 0; //in order to hide progress bar
        });
```

Spring controller:

```
   @RequestMapping(value={"/upload"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public Document upload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request /*@RequestBody MultipartFile file*/){

        Document resultHolder = new Document();
        try {
            String objectId =  request.getParameter("objectId");
            Collection<MultipartFile> files = request.getFileMap().values();
            Iterator it = files.iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()) {
                MultipartFile file = (MultipartFile) it.next();
                System.out.println(new String(file.getOriginalFilename().getBytes("iso-8859-1"),"UTF-8"));
                docService.upload(file, objectId);
            }
            resultHolder.put("result", "success");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            resultHolder.put("result", "fail");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultHolder;
    }
```

Replace my Documnt to your StatusDto. **Key point:** use `MultipartHttpServletRequest`

Important - if you are sending some UTF-8 params you should use
String param=  new String(request.getParameter("param").getBytes("iso-8859-1"),"UTF-8"); The same for `request.getOriginalFilename`  - for english letters it's OK but if filename contains UTF-8 characters use

```
String filename = new String(file.getOriginalFilename().getBytes("iso-8859-1"),"UTF-8"));
```